# Receiving and sending udp stream with one gst-launch-1.0 (gstreamer) command

Tags: command-line, 18.04, android, streaming, gstreamer

On an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop, I can receive a stream with the following gst-launch-1.0 commands:

The stream source (from a test brd that generates a test pattern):

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate =30/1 ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=10.0.0.2 port=5500
```

The above gst-launch sends a test pattern out on udp port 5500

I receive the above stream on an ubuntu laptop with:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5500 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
```

I am able to send from the ubuntu laptop a different test pattern stream to an Android device with a separate gst-launch command:

The gst-launch stream sent to the android device:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480" ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=10.100.46.40 port=5000
```

The above stream displays properly on the Android device.

I then try to connect the two so that I can receive the board's test pattern stream on the ubuntu laptop, and then pass that test pattern stream to the Android device, all within the same commandline like so:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e udpsrc port=5500 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=(int)96" ! rtph264depay ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! udpsink host=10.100.46.40 port=5000O
```

From this I get the following error:

> WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0: Attempting to send a UDP packets larger than maximum size (460800 > 65507)
> Additional debug info:
> gstmultiudpsink.c(722): gst_multiudpsink_send_messages (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
> Reason: Error sending message: Message too long

And nothing shows up on the Android device.  Is there a way to combine the two commands into one so that the Ubuntu laptop, is pretty much the middle man in this stream?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

My initial answer would be adding a buffer between payloader and sink element.

Just like this

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! video/x-raw, width=640, height=480, framerate =30/1 ! omxh264enc ! rtph264pay ! rndbuffersize min=50000 max=60000! udpsink host=10.0.0.2 port=5500
```

anything below 65507 should work..